# Python: using range() with " ".join()

Tags: python, string, join, integer, range

```
x = WAIT100MS
subroutines = ["WAIT"+str(range(1,256))+"MS"]
if x in subroutines:
    print "success"
else:
    print "invalid"
```

I'm trying to create a piece of code where if `WAITXMS` is between `1` and `255`, it will be accepted, otherwise it will not.
the range() function just generates a list, so I thought I would be able to use

`" ".join("WAIT"+str(range(1,256))+"MS")`,

to end up with a string like `x`.
However using the `join()` function with `range()` doesn't seem to work like I'd expect, and instead gives me a list as normal like `"WAIT[1,2,3,4,...]MS"`. What should I do?

Comment: mgilson's answer will solve the immediate issue, but really, you should be using a regex here.

Comment: Think about the order things are happening. You generate the range, then turn it into a string, then try to do a join. Things are out of order.

Comment: Do you actually need this `list` for any purpose other than checking `if x in subroutines`? If so, then Mark Ransom has explained the problem and mgilson the solution. If not, then (a) it's better as a `set` than a `list`, and (b) it's better to not generate it explicitly in the first place, presumably using some form of string processing, and NPE has provided a great solution.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want something like:

```
''.join("WAIT%dMS"%i for i in range(1,256))
```

Here's a better way I think:

```
def accept_string(s):
    try:
        i = int(s[4:-2])
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return s.startswith('WAIT') and s.endswith('MS') and (1 <= i < 256)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Small syntax error... i = int(s[4:-2])) should be i = int(s[4:-2]) 

otherwise brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
x = "WAIT100MS"
m = re.match(r"WAIT(\d+)MS$", x)
accept = m is not None and 1 <= int(m.group(1)) <= 255
```

I think that iterating over all acceptable numbers (let alone building and storing all `WAIT<n>MS` strings) is unnecessarily wasteful.

Comment: Ahh, so this is what OP wanted to do.  I was having a hard time figuring out what OP was attempting ...

Answer (score 1):

Why re when you can slice?

```
x = 'WAIT100MS'
n = int(x[4:-2])
if 1 < n < 256:
    print 'success'
else:
    print 'invalid'
```

Comment: This fails to accept `WAIT1MS`, and can wrongly accept inputs that don't start with `WAIT` or end with `MS`.

Comment: Actually it accepts 'WAIT1MS', tried with both 2.x and 3.x and it works. Your solution with re of course describes better the need but if you take for granted the syntax then slicing is the pragmatic way.

Comment: I hate to go on about this, but how can `1 < 1 < 256` evaluate to `True`, which is what you appear to be saying?

Comment: Oh right, my bad, I thought you said the slicing part. just change the 1 for 0 and we're good to go.